# Video streaming on flask no errors but it is only running the app not displaying on the browser

Tags: python, html, opencv, image-processing, flask

I want to stream a video on flask frame work. I initially tries to stream a camera video. There is no errors but it not working. Actually it does not stream on html page.It loads the html page but not displaying the video i want.

```
app.py:

import cv2
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # return the rendered template
    return render_template("view.html")

def gen():
    while True:
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret == False:
            continue
        # encode the frame in JPEG format
        encodedImage = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(np.array(encodedImage)) + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

This is my html code.

```
view.html:

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pi Video Surveillance</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pi Video Surveillance</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` outside `while True:` in `def gen():`.

Below is the modified `def gen()` function:

```
def gen():
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret == False:
            continue
        # encode the frame in JPEG format
        encodedImage = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(np.array(encodedImage)) + b'\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mehul Purohit answer will encounter follow issue.

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
```

Change this following is work for me.

```
yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Comment: perhaps explain what you changed and why. perhaps review [answer].